# cloning a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model in Rails that I would like to use as a basis for another.

For example model: **parent** will be the template for model **child**.
I can see two possible options:

(1) Inherit from the first model and then add additional columns

```
Class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
Class Child < Parent
```

(2) Copy the model.rb file and add new features

```
Class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
```

In both cases the "Rails" part of the model is created, but what about the database table? I could create the table using **create table child as select * from parent where 1=2** and then create migrations to add the additional columns, but it doesn't seem like the "Rails way".

Is there an easy way to create a migration based on an existing table. or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (1) is called [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) (STI). Basically you use one table that has both the fields of the parent and the child. You'll also need a column called `type` to identify the type of the object.

Without more details I can't say if it's a good idea to use STI in your case, but (2) copying model.rb certainly doesn't seem right.

Comment: I see. And what about the second instance where I want to copy but not inherit. Do I still need to create the table manually?

Comment: Yes, in that case you need a separate table for children, but duplicating code doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @ardichhigh If you want two different models to share some logic, you can extract it to module.

Comment: @ardochhigh  What do you mean exactly by template? How are you going to use this?

Comment: @Mischa Thanks for the tip, I'm really active on StackOverflow for about a month.

Comment: What I meant by template is a loose idea. For example in a large database I might have several similar tables that are not directly related. @Marek Lipka how would the Module extract work - that sounds good.

Comment: If you extract duplicate stuff into modules, you'll still need separate tables.